# How to make a sleep or full pause in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, setinterval, delay

I need to make a delay or sleep to full pause the code

I this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Hello")
}, 2000)

console.log("World")
```

But the log "World" prints first

Previously I'm using python and I used a code:

```
print("Hello")

time.sleep(2000)

print("World")
```

It's a success the word "Hello" prints first before world because of the **time.sleep()**

but I'm searching javascript code

If there's a code for it please share

Comment: _"I tried"_ Please show, not tell. Edit the question and include a [mcve] of you efforts.

Comment: Hello, the use of setTimeout was the right answer.
Just put the code you want to execute first before this function, and the code you want to execute after 2 secondes inside it.

console.log("Hello")
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("World")
}, 2000)

Comment: As [M.Hassan Nasir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432953/how-to-make-a-sleep-or-full-pause-in-javascript#comment119190848_67432953) said, [the answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/12425097).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function wait() {
  console.log('sleeping...');
  await sleep(2000); // 2000 ms = 2 sec
  console.log('done');
}

wait();
```

Comment: any code reliant on this must be inside a promise or async function.